# Best methods to do Point lights

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am trying to do directx 11 stuffs and i want to know what is the best method to implement point lights , likes 2000 of them in a level...

Currently i am doing a tutorial of rastertek ... and it is implementing light with shader class ... i think there is one 3d model per shader class, he is also declaring NUM_LIGHTS in shader , 4 in tutorials...

I want to have multiple 3d models and want to implement multiple point lights affecting them ... how to do it...

Comment: You should add tags for those fields, not just c++

Comment: Having been familiar with Rastertek, the example is in relation to dynamic lighting.  You can obviously extend this, with testing if its in the visible set of lights, then adding it to your list.  I would advise not extending this to 2000 lights. 
 Many engines will "pre-bake" the lighting with lightmaps, and limit the light interaction to dynamic objects (objects that move in your scene).
There are a few tutorials out there on this very subject, but you should first define what your vision is and then define what problems you face.  Good luck.

Comment: first i want to create a rendering demo of all directx 11 features then i will optimise it for game... now in rastertek tutorial he is declaring num lights in shader ... how can i manage 2000 lights in shader.. with his way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Forward+](https://www.3dgep.com/forward-plus/) is the way to go currently. By implementing Forward+, you also get a free depth pre-pass, which you can use in other rendering techniques/procedures too, for example [HBAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion), which stands for "Horizon Based Ambient Occlusion"

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing forward lighting, 4 to 8 lights is a common limit without starting to hurt the frame rate. If you're an absolute beginner I recommend to just use 8 lights for now until you have a better understanding of D3D11 api. When you've familiarized yourself with the API and are comfortable changing your renderer's program structure, you can look into a more advanced lighting scheme such as deferred lighting or forward+ lighting. There's a good blog article describing all three (Forward, Deferred and Forward+) lighting [techniques](https://www.3dgep.com/forward-plus/) using DirectX 11. With the source is available on Github. Another resource is [Learning Opengl](https://learnopengl.com/) which describes deferred lighting as well.